# Vector custom sum

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I need to identify the position of a variable from an integer array who has the following properties:

- the sum of elements before this variable is equal with the sum of elements after this variable
- if the variable doesn't exist, i will show a message.

For example, if `x = {1,2,4,2,1}`, the result is `4` with position `2`, because `1 + 2 == 2 + 1`.
Any suggestions? In this example it's easy

```
if((x[0]+x[1])==(x[3]+x[4]))
print position 2
```

But for `n` variables?

Comment: have you tried a loop?

Comment: Loop through all elements in the array and test for the condition you specified

Comment: For each index, compute the sum of preceding values (ones with lesser index) and the sum of following values (ones with greater index).   If the two sums are equal, you have found a match.   If not, continue to next index.   Repeat until either a match is found or all indices have been considered.

Comment: You can start with two variables, `before = 0;` and `after = sum_of_everything;`. Then visit each element and adjust those values using the visited one. Stop if they turn out to match.

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways to do this:

**Brute force - n/2 passes:**

- Loop through the array.
- For each element calculate the sum before and after that element.
- If they match you found the element.
- If the sum before becomes larger than the sum after, stop processing - no match found.

This is not really efficient for larger arrays.

**1.5 passes:**

- Calculate the sum of all elements.
- Divide that sum by 2 (`half_sum`).
- Start summing the elements again from the beginning until you reach `half_sum`.
- Check if you found a valid element or not.

**Single pass (positive numbers only):**

- Keep two running sums: one from the beginning (`sum1`) and one from the end (`sum2`).
- Set `sum1 = first element` and `sum2 = last element`.
- Check for the smallest of the two and add the next/previous element to that.
- Loop until the positions meet and check if the element is a valid result.

For each method you'll have to do a litlle check first to see if the array is not too small.

**Special cases to consider:**

- Empty array: return false
- Array with 1 element: return element
- Array with 2 nonzero elements: return false
- What with all zero's, or groups of zero's in the middle? (see Deduplicator's comment)
- Negative elements: single pass version will not work here (see Cris Luengo's comment)
- Negative elements in general: not reliable, consider +3 +1 -1 +1 -1 +3 +1 (see Deduplicator's comment)

Comment: As an aside, 1.5 passes is probably more efficient than 1 pass due to branch-predicition and caching.

Comment: I'm not sure the single-pass method would work if there are negative array elements.

Comment: @Deduplicator True, I was thinking about that too. However I think I read somewhere that modern CPU's (L1 cache) handle reverse memory access (almost) as good as forward access. But indeed, branch prediction and a thighter loop might make a diffference. Otoh having more instructions in the loop could make them execute at the same clock cycle (as in loop unrolling for example). So it would be an interesting test.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the **O(n)** solution.

Keep summing in in one variable from array beginning(`left_sum`) and keep deducing from the sum of elements except the first one using another(`right_sum`). When both becomes equal break the loop and print. Otherwise, show your msg.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <cstddef>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec {1,2,4,2,1};

    int left_sum = 0;
    int right_sum = std::accumulate(vec.cbegin()+1, vec.cend(), 0);

    bool Okay = false;
    std::size_t index = 1; // start from index 1 until n-1
    for( ; index < vec.size() - 1; ++index)
    {
        left_sum += vec[index-1];
        right_sum -= vec[index];
        if(left_sum == right_sum)
        {
            Okay = true;
            break;
        }
        // in the case of array of positive integers
        // if(left_sum > right_sum) break;
    }
    (Okay) ? std::cout << vec[index] << " " << index << std::endl: std::cout << "No such case!\n";
    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: You could optimize a bit by breaking when `left_sum > right_sum`. Also, see my single pass example :)

Comment: @Danny_ds You are right. Let me update with that. Thanks BTW.

Comment: You know dividing by two is quite efficient, and thereafter you only need to add to one sum?

Comment: The `if(left_sum > right_sum) break;` part is wrong if you allow negative array elements.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Good point, Have edited. I have only considered OPs case. Thanks for pointing out. :) One more case is, what if the size of the array < 3 ? I leave it to the OP to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for answers. I finally managed it. I used 3 for loops, and s0 is for sum before the element, and s1 is the sum after the element.

```
 for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {s1=0;
    s0=0;
        for(int j=0;j<i-1;j++)
                s0=s0+v[j];
        for(int k=i;k<n;k++)
            s1=s1+v[k];
        if(s0==s1)
            {cout<<endl<<"Position i="<<i;
            x++;}

    }
    if(x==0)
        cout<<"doesnt exist";
```

Comment: This is the brute force approach and not very efficient for larger arrays.

Comment: Have a look at @Jejo his answer. This gives you a nice insight of how you can optimize this.

Answer (score 1):

Well, do it in two steps:

1. Sum all elements.
2. From first to last:

   1. If the sum equals the current element, success!
   2. Subtract it twice from the sum (once for no longer being on the right, once for being on the left).

Use standard algorithms and range-for, and it's easily written:

```
auto first_balanced(std::span<const int> x) noexcept {
    auto balance = std::accumulate(begin(x), end(x), 0LL);
    for (auto&& n : x) {
        if (balance == n)
            return &n;
        balance -= 2 * n;
    }
    return end(x);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's just looping. You need to sum the elements before and after each index and just compare these two sums:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main() {

    std::vector<int> x = {1, 2, 4, 2, 1};

    for ( unsigned idx = 0; idx < x.size(); ++idx )
        if ( std::accumulate(x.begin(), x.begin() + idx, 0) == std::accumulate(x.begin() + idx + 1, x.end(), 0) )
            std::cout << idx << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is a O(n*n) solution though.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to build a solution out of std::algorithm, 
n+lg n instead of n+~n/2

Warning untested code.

```
bool HasHalfSum(int& atIndex, const std::vector<int>& v) {
  std::vector<int> sum;
  sum.reserve(v.size);

  std::partial_sum(v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_iterator(sum));
  // 1,3,7,9,10

  int half = sum.back() / 2; // 5

  auto found = std::lower_bound(sum.begin(), sum.end(), half);

  if (found != sum.begin() && std::prev(found) == sum.back() - *found) {
    index = std::distance(sum.begin(), found);
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}
```